# jquery loop: .html + .fadeIn

Tags: jquery

I made some script from Jquery for loop text. I want put some .fadeIn() on it, but can't. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myClasses = ["ONE", "TWO", "THERE", "FOUR"];    
    var count = 0;

    setInterval(function () {

        $(".one").html(myClasses[count]) 
        count >= 3 ? count = 0 : count += 1;
    }, 1200);
});
```

Comment: `fadeIn()` where do you want it? which element should be fadeIn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var myClasses = ["ONE", "TWO", "THERE", "FOUR"];    
        var count = 0;

        setInterval(function () {
            $(".one").fadeOut('slow',function(){
                $(this).html(myClasses[count]);
                count >= 3 ? count = 0 : count += 1;
            }).fadeIn("slow");
        }, 1200);
  });
```

Comment: I'd make it more dynamic - `count = count >= myClasses.length-1 ? 0 : count + 1;`